# Limit measuring failure of sum-set cancellability

Tags: combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, sumset

Suppose $A$, $B$ are finite sets of positive integers.

Let $$\mathcal{S}_n =  \{C \subset [1,n] \, : \, A+C = B+C \}, $$ and denote $a_n = |\mathcal{S}_n|$.

Note that for any $X \in \mathcal{S}_n$ and $Y \in \mathcal{S}_m$, the set $X \cup (Y+n) \subset [1,m+n]$ is in $\mathcal{S}_{m+n}$, hence $a_m \cdot a_n \le a_{m+n}$ for all $m$, $n$.

By Fekete's Lemma, it follows that $$m(A, B) :=  \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$$ exists and is finite, in particular $0\le m(A, B) \le 2$.

If $A$ and $B$ do not have the same least and greatest elements, then $m(A,B) = 0$; if they do, then $m(A,B) \ge 1$. If $A = B$, then $m(A,B) = 2$.

> What can we say about $m(A,B)$ in general? Can we compute it given $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Answered on mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/264744/limit-measuring-failure-of-sum-set-cancellability/